# SQL Query Codeigniter Query Builder PHP

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I need to query the database where the **total_pago** must equal the **valor** in the table **contas_pagar**

```
class Phpexcel_model extends CI_Model {

function get_users() {
    
    $query = $this->db->get_where("contas_pagar", array('total_pago' == 'valor'));
           
    return $query->result_array();
    
}
```

[Database image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nUuKU.png)

As the image the result should bring only the data that match the query, but it is bringing all the data from the table

Answer (score 0):

According to the docs (https://codeigniter.com/userguide3/database/query_builder.html#selecting-data) you want the following (note `==` vs `=>`):

```
->get_where('contas_pagar', array('total_pago' => 'valor'))
```

What you have now is evaluating to

```
->get_where('contas_pagar', array(false))
```

because in PHP the string `'total_pago'` is not equal to `'valor'`.

Comment: This probably won't work... Even though you make a valid point with the `=>` vs `==`, the `where` clause is still looking for a string (`'valor'`) in what appears to be a numeric field (`total_pago`)

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `total_pago` is a numeric field and `valor` is a variable that contains a number, your `get_where` statement should be:

```
->get_where('contas_pagar', array('total_pago' => $valor))
```

Answer (score 0):

you can use this to inspect your query. so that we can see the whole query that is executed by the mysq/sql and so that we can check where the error occur

```
echo $this->db->last_query()
```

also alternatively you can use the custom query

```
$this->db->query('SELECT * FROM contas_pagar WERE total_pago=? ',[$valor])->result_array()
```

Answer (score -1):

```
function get_users() {
    
    $query = $this->db->get_where("contas_pagar", array('total_pago' => 'valor'));
           
    return $query->result_array();
    
}
```

Comment: If you use `get_where` you don't also need `$query->get()`

Comment: I didn't understand the answer, could you explain it better?